# Visual Studio solution containing multiple solutions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

What is the difference between a Visual Studio solution and a Visual Studio project.  I have read questions like this: [Visual Studio Project vs. Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389226/visual-studio-project-vs-solution)

I am specifically interested in solutions that contain multiple solutions.  Why would a solution that contains many solutions be used instead of one solution that contains many projects?

I support and develop solutions that contain multiple projects.

Comment: Please read your question and correct it. `What is the difference between a Visual Studio solution and a Visual Studio.`. And a Visual Studio what?

Comment: This question barely makes sense!  Does the author mean solutions vs. projects?

Comment: Thanks Oded.  I missed out a single word: project.  Sorry if this caused confusion.  I have edited the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a solution contain solutions. Period.

Solutions are containers for projects and items shared between projects. They also track dependencies between projects.

Comment: I was confusing myself looking at some source code, which I downloaded online (open source).  Can you explain what you mean by: "track dependencies between projects"

Comment: @w0051977 - What don't you understand about that statement? Do you know that you can add a project reference to a project? Solutions are where the meta data for this is stored.

Comment: I understand that a dependency occurs when a reference is created from one project to another.  I don't fully understand why a solution that contains multiple projects helps to "manage" dependencies, except for the fact that all references are created and removed in one place i.e. one solution.  Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 - There is an implicit build order to the projects, that Visual Studio can get wrong. The manual changes to this are stored in the solution file.